# how to add listener in asp.net webservice?

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, listener

I want to make an asynchronous call to a ASP.NET web service from client app which is a C# windows forms app. I did it successfully but my problem is when I call the web service it listens for some other client for permission to return the result to the caller client. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You need to expand and clarify your question more. Do you mean that client1 should only recieve a response from the service if some other client2 gives permission? Does client2 give permission for each response, or does it give permission once for all responses to client1? Either way, this is a complex problem with no quick and easy solution.

Comment: client2 give permission for each response. but untill client2 give the permission call need to be wait in webservice